# Querying a data knowledge in prolog

Tags: prolog

Let's say i have some data in this form:

```
plot('Jurrassic Park",'action')
plot('Jurrassic Park",'drama')
plot('Jurrassic Park",'adventure')
plot('pulp fiction",'retro')
plot('pulp fiction",'crime')
....
```

where in `plot(X,Y) X` is a movie and `Y` is this movies genre.

What i would like to do is query this database and get all the movies that have 3 equal genres.
For example if there is another movie that is action,drama,adventure i would like it to be paired with Jurassic park.What i have done so far:

```
predic(X,Y,Z,Z2,Z3):-
   plot(X,Z), plot(Y,Z), X \= Y,
   plot(X,Z2), plot(Y,Z2), X \= Y, Z\=Z2,
   plot(X,Z3), plot(Y,Z3), X \= Y, Z\=Z3,Z2\=Z3
```

The problem is that this may return multiple instances of moves (X,Y)(i want it to return just one) because it returns all the possible combinations between `Z,Z2,Z3`.It will return `(Jurassic Park,Jurassic World,action,adventure,drama)` and it will also return `(Jurassic Park,Jurassic World,action,drama,adventure)`.

So how could i make my query stop after finding the 1st combination of `Z,Z2,Z3` which satisfies the predicates needs?
I can't use `"!"` because i want this query to return all the possible pairs of movies with 3 common genres and not just 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can enforce order in the terms `Zi`, by adding constraints `Zi @< Zi+1`. Here we thus use the [**`(@<)/2`** predicate [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(@%3C)/2), that checks the *standard order* on terms:

```
predic(X, Y, Z1, Z2, Z3) :- 
    plot(X, Z1), plot(Y,Z1),
    X \= Y,
    plot(X, Z2), plot(Y,Z2),
    Z1 @< Z2,
    plot(X, Z3), plot(Y,Z3),
    Z2 @< Z3.
```

If you are only interested in distinct sets of two movies being similar, you can make use of the [**`distinct/1`**](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=distinct/1) meta-predicate:

```
predic(X, Y) :-
    predic(X, Y, _, _, _).

similars(X, Y) :-
    distinct(predic(X, Y)).
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not solve the problem.The thing is that in my example in the first solution Z1,Z2,Z3=action,adventure,drama and then Z1,Z2,Z3=action,drama,adventure and enforcing order between these does not stop that from happening.What i would like somehow to do is stop further searching after Z1,Z2,Z3 are all unified for the first time.

Comment: @PAPARI: If they have four (or more) genres in common, then of course it will unify more, since then the values for `Z1`, etc. are different. You can use meta-predicates like `once/1` and `distinct/1`, but just like cut, it makes the logic less "pure" imho.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use the standard aggregation setof, basic list processing, and pattern matching:

```erlang
predic(X, Y, A,B,C) :-
  setof(P, Q^plot(P, Q), Ps),
  append(_, [X|Ys], Ps),
  member(Y, Ys),
  setof(P, P^plot(X,P), [A,B,C|_]),
  setof(P, P^plot(Y,P), [A,B,C|_]).
```