# count number of correct answers and check..prolog

Tags: python, prolog, google-colaboratory

I want to asser into my prolog database a predicate that finds all the movies that have less than 2 common genres.
[same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59514597/querying-a-data-knowledge-in-prolog)

```
prolog.assertz('(havesamegenre(X, Y) :- genre(X, G), genre(Y, G), X \= Y )')
prolog.assertz('(not_relative_genre(X, Y) :- aggregate_all(count, havesamegenre(X ,Y), Count), X \= Y, Count < 2)')
```

Calling the above code :

```
movie = "Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith"
q = prolog.query("not_relative_genre('" + movie +"',M)")
ans = []
for soln in q:
    if soln["M"] not in ans:
        ans.append(soln["M"])
print (ans[:10] )
```

and I get an empty list , although there are answers that satisfy this predicate in my database.

Comment: Does it work when you query this at the Prolog REPL? That would tell you if it's a problem on the Prolog side or Python side.

Comment: I have only tried this on google's colaboratory.

Comment: I have put [your problem](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/musicdatabase.pl) into SWISH. Now you can experiment without the overhead of python. `havesamegenre/2` works (as long as all your `genre/2` facts don't contain variables) as expected but `not_relative_genre/2` does not give the answer you'd like. As a next step, you could make the `aggregate` goal a query to see if it does what you want and add more goals until the solutions are lost. That would be a promising point to debug.

Comment: I'm not sure what `not_relative_genre` is expressing but my intuition is that there is a simpler solution. (My impression is that you formulation is close to SQL where you first create a list of all solutions and filter them. That's usually the hard way to go in Prolog even though it cannot always be avoided)

Comment: not_relative_genre/2 is supposed to get 2 movies as input and say if they have one or none common genres. What solution would you suggest?

Comment: Seems like aggregate over aggregate_all solves my problem. Thanks for you time!

Comment: So `not_relative_genre(X,Y)` is true if `X` and and `Y` are movies that do not share a genre? Just use `nrt(X,Y) :- dif(G1, G2), genre(G1, X), genre(G2, Y)`.

Comment: I think I want it to be true when X,Y have one or none common genres.

Comment: Ah ok that's what you mean - you can't get around much cheaper when you have cardinality constraints on a predicate then. You can express exactly one solution as having one in common and having no other in common (`dif(G1, G2), genre(G1, M1), genre(G2, M2), dif(G1, G3), dif(G2,G3), \+ (genre(G3, X), genre(G3, Y)).`) but the negation in there is a similar one that you need for the implementation of aggregate.